# Network Bridge for VM not working after reboot

Tags: networking, kvm, bridge, libvirt, virsh

I have a CentOS 7 host with a network bridge set up for guest VM's to use. All was well until a recent reboot. After the reboot, the guest VM does not have internet access, nor can it ping other local addresses (and other local machines cannot ping the guest) The host machine has internet access, and I can SSH into it from within the LAN.

I have the following files in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` on the **host system**:

**ifcfg-br0:**

```
STP=no
TYPE=Bridge
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=none
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
NAME=br0
UUID=3feaa236-2ea8-4024-9667-d446e952fc44
DEVICE=br0
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=192.168.1.130
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
ONBOOT=yes
```

**ifcfg-bridge-slave-enp0s25:**

```
TYPE=Ethernet
NAME=bridge-slave-enp0s25
UUID=b9e60eb8-b9f8-497c-89f6-40d60b4bced8
DEVICE=enp0s25
ONBOOT=yes
BRIDGE=br0
```

**ifcfg-enp0s25:**

```
TYPE=Ethernet
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=none
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
NAME=enp0s25
UUID=a4799b47-9042-4a95-925c-d1d364fc99de
DEVICE=enp0s25
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=192.168.1.131
PREFIX=24
GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
DNS1=8.8.8.8
DNS2=8.8.4.4
IPV6_PRIVACY=no
```

**GUEST SYSTEM'S /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0**

```
TYPE="Ethernet"
PROXY_METHOD="none"
BROWSER_ONLY="no"
BOOTPROTO="none"
DEFROUTE="yes"
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
IPV6INIT="yes"
IPV6_AUTOCONF="yes"
IPV6_DEFROUTE="yes"
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE="stable-privacy"
NAME="eth0"
UUID="7c2087a0-7d4b-4e3a-ac71-07b8dcac07ad"
DEVICE="eth0"
ONBOOT="yes"
IPADDR="192.168.1.132"
PREFIX="24"
GATEWAY="192.168.1.1"
DNS1="8.8.8.8"
DNS2="8.8.4.4"
```

The VM was installed with `virt-install` using the `--network bridge=br0` argument, and it was able to access the web, serve web pages via apache, and it could be pinged my other computer in the LAN.

What can I do next to get this guest VM back on the network through the `br0` network bridge?

Comment: @roaima Hey, I had actually deleted that comment and up voted you. It appears that this has actually restored my network access to the VM. I hooked up a monitor and keyboard to that server and rebooted, and everything was perfect. I think that the server itself just appeared to be on (orange power light) but didn't actually reboot. If you'd like to reply with an answer, I'll gladly accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have CentOS to hand, but I can speak from extensive experience in Debian.

Generally speaking, bridge configurations require that the interface itself (in your case `enp0s25`) is not configured with an IP address. The physical interface remains unconfigured but UP and RUNNING, and the IP configuration for the host gets applied to logical bridge interface instead.

I'd suggest changing the file `ifcfg-enp0s25` to have `ONBOOT=no` and trying again.

If that doesn't work, delete the `ifcfg-enp0s25` file (ie move it some place safe) because you've got the requisite settings in the slave file.